# Apache2 + Laravel wildcard subdomain routing

Tags: laravel, apache, .htaccess

I'm building webapp on Ubuntu + Apache2 with wildcard SSL certificates

My goal is to set up functioning project on 1st level domain `project.app` as well as several subdomains `marketplace.project.app` & `partners.project.app`

All of the project files are under the same directory:

```
www/project/
```

subdomains accessible via laravel router:

```
Route::domain('marketplace.project.app')->group(function () {
    Route::view('','pages.marketplace');
});
```

serverside DNS records:

```
A | project.app | 127.0.0.1
A | *.project.app | 127.0.0.1
```

/sites-available/default-ssl.conf:

```
                ServerName project.app
                ServerAlias *.project.app
                DocumentRoot /var/www/project/public

                <Directory /var/www/project>
                        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                        AllowOverride All
                        Order allow,deny
                        allow from all
                </Directory>
```

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^127\.0\.0\.1
RewriteRule (.*) https://project.app/$1 [R=301,L]
```

All of the wildacrd subdomains e.g. `bbb.project.app` work flawlessly, but upon accessing app in browser via 1st level `project.app` apache does not render index.php file.

Is the setup I'm thriving for feasible in apache or should I switch to Ngnix?

Answer (score 0):

Just to alert, You do not really need to use htaccess rules once you use apache2, ybecause "blahblahblah.conf" can handle htaccess rules.

To handle multiple domains and including htaccess rules with it, you can do the following (working example):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias foo.example.com bar.example.com others.example.com
    
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/laravel_folder/public"
    <Directory /var/www/laravel_folder/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [or]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com [or]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =foo.example.com [or]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.foo.example.com [or]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =bar.example.com [or]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.bar.example.com [or]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =others.example.com [or]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.others.example.com 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```